# If my program use a project with MIT, but I modified some code of it, than do I need to mention that I use this project?

Tags: mit, license

Does MIT require people must to mention the project that they use code or binary files obtained under this license? Even users close source or modified it?

And how about only the binary file or folder with this project name in the program directory?

MIT requere inlude the MIT licence, and how will if I used any other MIT licence project? Can I merge them?

And, which of the following actions does not meet MIT's minimum requirements?

```
                           | No mention | mention only | licence only |
Use binary files           |            |              |              |
Use full code              |            |              |              |
Use modified full code     |            |              |              |
Use code fragment          |            |              |              |
Use modified code fragment |            |              |              |  [V][X]
```

Comment: Your choice of license does not free you from the obligations of the licenses of code you include in parts or completely. What exactly is not clear about the MIT license? It's short enough you could have discussed every single sentence in your question. Sorry to say, but currently your question reads like 'meh, please do my homework for me'.

Comment: @planetmaker I think I read it too much, but I still don't know about "tell others I this program used this MIT project" is MIT license required obligation or not. So, I must have to mention this MIT project and place the MIT License file under my program, even if I make any changes about MIT project, yeah?

Comment: @planetmaker but this link tell me MIT not required the modified versions must be issued under the same license: https://paulmillr.com/posts/simple-description-of-popular-software-licenses/

Comment: well, I've found a same question here now, I will flag this question is duplicate.

Comment: Did you read the license?

Comment: @user253751 I've read it, but I'm just caught up in some details. All of all, I don't need to think any details. Facing the MIT licence, I just should find a place to put the license content, that's all.

Comment: Your requirement is precisely what the license says. Not more, not less.